# Trendline formula in R

Tags: r, correlation, linear-model

I have created a simple scatterplot to analyse the correlation between two variables, x and y. Using the abline command, I added a trendline to this data. I now want to know the formula for this trendline. Is there a command that will give this formula as one is able to do in a simple Excel scatterplot?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Kait. Note that purely R questions belong on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), whereas CV is for questions about the statistical content. We will migrate your Q over there for you in time(*please don't cross-post SE strongly discourages this*), but 1st we should help you formulate it (here are a couple of relevant discussions: [how-to-ask-question-related-to-the-use-of-r](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/), & [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/)). Can you paste your code into your Q?

Comment: I for one provided an example on [how to display regression equation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9571807/420055) in a scatter plot on Stack Overflow. There are plenty of other related threads, IMO, and SO is better suited for such questions.

Answer (score 5):

This should get you going.

```
x <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE)
y <- x + rnorm(100, sd = 4)
mydf <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
plot(y ~ x, data = mydf)
model <- lm(y ~ x, data = mydf)
abline(model, col = "red")
summary(model)
coef(model)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Search for `lm` command and you can get linear model formula from it.